Is it usual for instructors to adapt their accent to seem more "professional"?
I’ve noticed that my American-born mathematics professor seems to adopt a different accent when giving lectures: one that sounds more “standard American” or “neutral” compared to how they speak in casual conversation or office hours. I’m curious if this phenomenon is common in academia, particularly in math departments (or STEM fields generally). Is it considered normal or even encouraged for professors to change their accent in order to project a more “professional” image in class?
Additionally, I wonder how students and colleagues generally react to this. Does it provide any tangible benefit — e.g., clearer enunciation for non-native English speakers, or greater perceived authority — or might it create an unintended barrier between the professor and students? Are there cultural or institutional norms around modifying one’s accent in academic settings?
I’d be especially interested in hearing from those who have either tried to neutralize their accent themselves or observed colleagues doing so. Is this mostly a personal choice, or are there departments or institutions that actively promote a certain “standard” accent for clarity? If so, do such expectations raise ethical or inclusivity concerns?
If anyone is curious, here is a scene from the movie “The Fugitive” which illustrates what I mean.

Please avoid writing answers in the comments. The answer box is mere inches away. Comments are for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements to the question, not for information that partially (or fully) answers the question.

Is there a reason you associate an affected accent with ‘more professional’?

Maybe you mean the instructor adopts more formal diction and articulation than what you’d hear at the weekly department coffee?

Do you mean "accent" or "dialect"? From a European standpoint I am used to people being rather flexible about their dialect but very rigid about their accent.

From a linguistic perspective, people shift accents all the time based on who they are talking to. This is a kind of code-switching, which we all do, all the time, mostly unconsciously (I don't text my friends like I write here).
For an American-born individual, very few American accents are considered "superior" or "standard" in the way Received Pronunciation is. Southern accents "sound dumb," and Boston accents are widely derided. Southern California dialects are ridiculed as "Valley Girl."
Thus, speaking with a regional American accent tends to have negative connotations, not positive ones. So it is pretty possible that someone who thinks they have an accent may, intentionally or unintentionally, shift toward something that's considered more "professional."
For the more academic questions,

Does it provide any tangible benefit? Yes, General American English is likely more intelligible to non-native speakers, and for the reasons described above, likely feels more professional.

Are there cultural or institutional norms around modifying one’s accent in academic settings? I don't know the answer to this. Universities tend tend to comprise people from all over, and I think it's unlikely universities in the South expect new arrivals to pick up the local accent.


For more discussion on non-native accents, see this question, although I disagree with the accepted answer (and its formatting).

+1, but I don't think "positive" and "negative" connotations necessarily have much to do with this. The motivation may simply be to sound more neutral. There is no need to postulate the the speaker has negative feelings towards their accent (or is afraid that other people do). In other words, you say that it is a shift toward something that is less negatively marked, but it can equally well just be a shift toward something that is less marked, period.

@AdamPřenosil The thing is, "neutral" is a value judgment as well. Accents that sound "neutral" are only so because that's how society treats them, they are not a natural kind.

I think there's room to say the prof doesn't feel negatively about her accent, and maybe I'll edit a tad, but "more professional," "more understandable," and "less regional" are all comparisons to her own accent.

Sure. I was just making the point that your answer makes it sounds like the speaker is worried about negative stereotypes associated with their accent, but that's just one of the possible/plausible motivations.

I still remember a friend in college who was from Missouri. When he talked to us, he sounded pretty "normal". But when he was on the phone with his family back home, the full southern drawl came out.

I think it's worth considering that "code switching" isn't necessarily intentional; humans seem to do it more or less automatically, at least to an extent. So, it's not necessarily the case that someone doing this has a particular benefit or norm in mind, they might not have really thought about it at all or even noticed they were doing it.

+1 more intelligible ... Sometimes I wish that more foreign mathematicians would get help on making their English more intelligible.

To reinforce the already solid answers which have previously been given, here's my personal experience:
I am an American-born professor of mathematics at a small liberal arts college in the US.  I have a noticeable (but not particularly strong) regional accent, and I teach in the region where I grew up.  I also naturally have a tendency to talk very quickly.
Our institution has a significant population of students whose primary language is not English, so I try to be cautious about how fast I speak and what terminology I use in the classroom.  That said, I don't intentionally change the pronunciation of any words.  To be honest, I have probably invested more thought into how I write than how I speak.
When a student visits office hours, I do find myself doing a bit of the "code-switching" described in a previous answer.  I can talk very fast and causally with students from my region, but I am much more deliberate in how I talk with our university's ESL students (we have some students who are conditionally accepted and must complete additional courses in English language before becoming "usual" full-time students, and math is often one of the first courses they take while finishing their English requirements).

My best guess, and only that, is that this is an individual thing. It might not even be recognized by the professor. I don't recall any such change in language or accent in my own teaching, but it is possible that it was there.
Many of us have had mentors in our own education and we try to emulate them. Perhaps this is a case of sounding like one's favorite professor in the past.
It is also possible that one might try to use more formal language when discussing more formal topics. The jargon of most fields might sound pompous to those not familiar with it, including students at the beginning of their studies.
But, this seems innocuous to me and you might consider asking the professor about it. If it is intentional, they may be willing to say why. If you called me out on it, assuming I did such a thing, I would probably laugh - Wow, I never realized that.
But for a direct answer, I doubt that many professors do such a thing with intention. Some, perhaps.
I do know that one student on RateMyProfessors described me as "arrogant". It puzzled me no end and it didn't seem to be the general view.

Echoing this... I've had students (native U.S. English speakers) in basic math courses complain in teaching evaluations that I "used big words, to try to impress them". :)

@paulgarrett, yes "mathematics" is a pretty big word. Also a "pretty" word.

I am not a native speaker and I can't help but try to sound more "standard American" when giving presentations, which makes little sense since I live in Europe. I think it's something almost everybody, in Academia or not, is conditioned to at this point.

Regarding the second paragraph, I did it without even realizing it in a presentation. By the way, I'm a student.

In my case (BFH Burgdorf in Switzerland), a so called "Standard language" (Standardsprache) was to be used by requirement of the school, by both Professors and Students, instead of the local dialect.
This lead to sometimes funny situations, where some "false friends" and hard to pronounce words were used. Sometimes pronounciations were inter-mixed. No one was doing this to appear more professional (the vast majority was fluent in the local dialect anyway), but this might have been the intent of the school.
For example, the ETH (Swiss Federal Institute of Technology) in Zurich, has a directive on language use in lectures.

Interestingly, that ETH document made me do a double-take already in the first sentence, because the Swiss Standard German word Naturwissenschafter doesn't exist in my native Standard German, where it would be Naturwissenschaftler. So, it seems when they write "German", they mean specifically "Swiss Standard German", but it doesn't seem to be spelled out in the document. I wonder what would happen if someone held a lecture in Bairisch or Berndüütsch :-D

Well, Zurich is in Switzerland. I'll bet they price things in francs instead of euros too.

Echoing others' comments and answers: it may or not be conscious, but people will "change their tone" (care in diction) when talking about the actual material at hand, as opposed to kidding around or joking. Yes, "code switching". I certainly do, but/and, by this time, without conscious effort. Yes, it is easy to intersperse facetious remarks with serious, and tone-of-voice is often the only distinguishing indicator. But, I think, the vast majority of students do enjoy it, and I've been told that this approach lightens up their day, as well as helping to keep them alert.
The downside is that non-native English speakers, and some neuro-divergent people, cannot easily hear the code-switch. I myself am not going to take that as a reason to eliminate the minor entertainment of a vast majority, but I do also take some care to not make it be a bottleneck for anyone at all.

Especially when dealing with (potential) non-native speakers it makes sense to use an accent and terminology that's more standard.  For me, in the UK, that approaches received pronunciation.  That's true whether presenting in a conference, lecturing, or working in small groups if clarity is important.  I grew up quite exposed to such an accent in school in London, especially from teachers, so perhaps it's natural for me to slip into it in a similar context.
My London accent is detectable at times in a work (academic) context, often in a lighter context and accompanied by greater use of non-obvious idioms.  That could be just chatting (with native speakers  who will follow, or non-native speakers who will ask for clarification and are interested in English).  In a lecture or seminar you might hear this less formal accent and language for an illustrative anecdote; there's an accompanying visual difference in how and where I stand.
This isn't uncommon; even if someone's lecturing voice still carries a strong accent of where they came from it's still more like standard British English than their conversational voice.
This is physics, but similar things are common in the corporate world in engineering as well (still in the UK).
